# Powering multiple external 12v devices (HDDs and Media player)

Tags: networking, external-hard-drive, power

I have two x 2TB external HDD drives with their individual 12 external power adapters and their usb outputs connected to a media player, which also has a 12 v external power adapter. What I'd like to know is - Can I purchase a single 12v power supply with three plugs for the 2 drives and the media player. I currently use up loads of wall power sockets - ie one for the media player, two for the drives. I'd like to reduce it to one ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you can find it. Make sure that it provides enough current to power all three devices, and prefer ones with isolated outputs if you can find them so that power noise from one doesn't affect the others.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your 2 12V adapters by one, but you need to know how many Amperes you will need. If one adapter delivers 1 A and the other 2 A you will need to purchase a 12V 3A adapter. then you can cut the cable and make a PARALELL connection (not a serial one, that will reduce the voltage and may damage your devices or make them unable to work!)

Here is a little schematical construction of such connection:

[image]

also remember that you connect the wires (+/-) correctly, in most adapters you only have a BLACK wire and a BLACK with WHITE STRIPES on them. It's important to to connect the correct ones together, if not sure which is which, the adapter label should show which side of the pin is + and which side is -. then use a multimeter to ensure the configuration of the cables is correct.